# Need help ordering a list of functions

Tags: functions, algorithms, induction, asymptotics, real-numbers

List the functions below from lowest order to highest order. If any two or more are of
the same order, indicate which.

$n$, $n^3$, $2^n$, $\ln n$, $n^2$, $\ln^2 n$, $\sqrt n$, $2^{n−1}$, $\ln n$, $e^n$

I made n = 2, plugged in the values and came up with the following order:

$\ln n$, $\ln^2 n$, $\ln n$, $\sqrt n$, $n$, $2^{n-1}$, $n^2$, $2^n$, $e^n$, $n^3$

I doubt this order is correct, I just do not know. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by lowest to highest?

Comment: Yes lowest to highest

Comment: That does not answer my question. What do you mean when you say you want them ordered lowest to highest? They are not strickly greater/less than each other

Comment: You have ln n in there twice - check if you're missing something (e.g. should one be n ln n or log_2 n or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists limit
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}=C,\qquad |C|<\infty,
$$

then we will assume that 
 
**functions have the same order**, if $0<|C|<\infty$, 
function $f(n)$ **has lower order than** $g(n)$, if $C=0$.

Use these well known limits:

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln n}{n^a}=0, \qquad a>0;
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{n^a}{b^n}=0, \qquad b>1.
$$

Then, for example,

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln n}{\lg n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln n}{\ln n / \ln 10}=\ln 10\ne 0;
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln n}{\ln^2 n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} \dfrac{1}{\ln n}=0;
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{2^n}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} 2=2\ne 0;
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{2^n}{e^n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left(\dfrac{2}{e}\right)^n= 0.
$$

So, order is as following:

- $\lg n$, $\ln n$ (they have the same order);
- $\ln^2 n$;
- $\sqrt{n}$;
- $n$;
- $n^2$;
- $n^3$;
- $2^{n-1}$, $2^n$ (they have the same order);
- $e^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct - your answer is wrong.

I assume that you are talking about [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). To answer the question:

1. Read the article, your notes and the textbook
2. Classify the functions by the notation the fall into - to help you have some linear, polynomial, exponential, logarithmic and quasilinier.
3. Within each classification decide which will grow faster.

Comment: So basically put them in order based on how long each function will run for?

Comment: Not exactly - the Big O notation is based on how long they will "run" (in idealized machines") as $n\to \infty$. As you have already found - this is not the same as $n=2$.

Comment: Not in terms of how long each function will run, but in terms of how long a program of *order* of that function will take to run, as the size of its input grows.